# Manually calculate font size for drawn NSAttributedString based on container width

Tags: uikit, nsattributedstring, uigraphicscontext

`UILabel` has the property `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` which calculates the perfect font size if the bounding box is smaller than what text can be displayed at the current font size.

I am drawing text on a `UIGraphicsImageRendererContext` which is then exported to an image. I would like to recreate the behavior of `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` with the `NSAttributedStrings` I am currently using. This is the code I use to draw:

```
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "Example Text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font.withSize(16)])
text.draw(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 20))
```

Is there a way to calculate the perfect font size based on the available width? I assume this would be an algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by finding the scale factor by diving the smaller container width with the proposed string width, then using that scale factor to determine a new font size.

```
var title = NSAttributedString(string: "Example", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font.withSize(fontSize)])

let titleWidth = title.size().width
if titleWidth > containerWidth {
  let scaleFactor = containerWidth / titleWidth
  title = NSAttributedString(string: title.string, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font.withSize(fontSize * scaleFactor)])
}
title.draw(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight))
```